# Protecting Apache and Nginx against slow read/write and similar attacks?

Tags: security, web-server, ddos

There are many articles explaining many ways to attack webservers (generic or specific) and even listing general rules for mitigating such attacks, e.g.:

- Do not accept connections with abnormally small advertised window sizes
- Drop connections that send request longer than X seconds
- Send RST or FIN after 30 seconds when client can't accept the data due to a full receive window
- Limit number of connections from same IP
- Drop more than X repetitive headers (such as `Range`)
- etc etc...

Are there ready to use, tested on prod configuration examples specific to webserver (we use Apache and Nginx) or system wide (Linux) that cover most common attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is a good one. As always, read it very carefully and do your homework - not all of this may suit your environment. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html

Comment: Be careful. Some of the advice given in that article is plain _bad_, such as the advice which blocks the Bing search engine.

Comment: Hence the note about doing your homework. Your statement - that blocking Bing is *bad* -  is exactly the broad brush advice I warn against above. All of this is case by case, and you need to evaluate it against your needs.